# Getting array to change value of class

Tags: javascript, impress.js

Essentially, this is inside of a function:

```
// Adding in an array of gradients
var bg = ["gradient-0", "gradient-1", "gradient-2", "gradient-3", "gradient-4", "gradient-5", "gradient-6", "gradient-7", "gradient-8"];

var i = 0, len = bg.length;
for (; i < len;) {
    body.classList.add(bg[i++]);
}
```

Right now, it spits out the gradients (1,2,3, etc) all at once.

**What I'm trying to do is to change the background of each 'slide' using impress.js**

(http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/#/bored)

*I've gotten it to change from 1 to 2, and from 1 to 2 to 1 on transition, but no avail on changing the color on each transition.*

Comment: Share some code, so that we know what have you tried so far

Comment: You need to include a lot more info about what you're doing and what exactly your question is before anyone can help.

Comment: just as a suggestion, when you have a loop with 1st and 3rd parameters empty, consider using a `while` instead